# Implementing a Download Listener in Fragment Webview from an URL String

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-webview

I am using webView to load url which I pass from next fragment as String

```
String url1 = getArguments().getString("url1");
```

and now as the webpage loads inside webView,I would like to add Download listener to download using external Browser.

My Fragment java code is

```
public class webb extends Fragment {

    WebView myWebView;
    private LinearLayout container;
    private Button nextButton, closeButton;
    private EditText findBox;
    ProgressBar pbar;

    public webb() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webb, container,  false);



        String url1 = getArguments().getString("url1");


        myWebView=(WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        pbar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        myWebView.setInitialScale(1);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();


        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl(url1);


        return rootView;


    }

    public static String changedHeaderHtml(String htmlText) {

        String head = "<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, user-scalable=yes\" /></head>";

        String closedTag = "</body></html>";
        String changeFontHtml = head + htmlText + closedTag;
        return changeFontHtml;

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url1) {
            //remove your progressdialog here
            super.onPageFinished(view, url1);
            pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url1) {

        myWebView.loadUrl(url1);
        return true;


    }
}
```

Someone Suggested me to use

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 

        // download your stuff here

        return false;
    }
```

But how do I load the string url1  inside webView using above solution??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the initial URL in the arguments when you build the fragment (BTW, you should really name it `Webb` and not `webb`):

```
public class webb extends Fragment {

    public static Webb createFragment(String url) {
        Webb webb = new Webb();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString("url1", url);
        webb.setArguments(arguments);
        return webb;
    }

}
```

If you want to open the external browser at a certain point, you can:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 

    if (!url.equals(getArguments().getString("url1"))) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivity(intent);  
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Then how do I implement download inside fragment....and I am sorry If  I sound stupid..but I'm really in very beginning. Everything I learn from error and mistakes and with help of you guys.

Comment: sorry but I must have done something wrong, as provided code is not working and it's throwing me error on shouldOpenExternalBrowserWithUrl and also on bool.

Comment: I didn't write the logic for the function, you have to fill it in by yourself depending on what you need

Comment: I am looking to pass string as url1 from another fragment and load the string url1 inside the webView in this fragment and also allow to download files from link which will use external browser to download the file....!! Now what should I write there...??

Comment: Try this version